# Wordpress - Removing default styles

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to create my own Wordpress theme just for a one page, secured form. This form looks as it should normally, as you can see in this screenshot --> [image]

Unfortunately, even though I've included my own reset.css file, WordPress is inheriting styles from the theme's style.css file. See here --> [image]

As you can see, the font size is much smaller, input fields aren't getting proper padding, the  body background is supposed to be blue but is a grayish color in the second screenshot, fields aren't getting proper margins etc.

I know everyone is going to be asking for code, but before I do that, I'm just wondering if there is a default css file you can delete or modify that most of these styles would be included on. I'm guessing this might be included in the admin bar that gives default margin to the top?

If I need to add code, please just let me know and I will. I'm just assuming there are some wordpress gurus out there who already know the answer to this question.

Thank you

Comment: If this in the backend or frontend of WordPress?

Comment: I'm assuming backend? I created my wordpress theme on my localhost and I copied and pasted code from original css page to style.css. Maybe I should just include the style.css info at the top and relocate all other styles to a separate css page?

Comment: If you are doing a theme, it's frontend. Backend is the administrative portion of WordPress, which you can create posts/pages in.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are some options:

- Go to `/wp-content/themes/YOUR-THEME/header.php` and remove any stylesheet includes.
- Go to `/wp-content/themes/YOUR-THEME/functions.php` and remove any `wp_enqueue_style()`
- Make sure the style isn't generated by a plugin. If it is, you can deregister the style. Here is a link explaining how: http://speakinginbytes.com/2012/09/disable-plugins-css-file/
- Overwrite the styles using your own stylesheet. Make sure your stylesheet comes LAST. You can do this a few ways - I'd recommend using `wp_enqueue_style()` with a dependency on the offending stylesheet.

Comment: Omg I feel so dumb now, I just had to move the stylesheet down to the bottom, one of my other stylesheets must have been messing it up. Thank you very much Shane :)

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to just delete the content below the theme info in the style.css file in wordpress and it will completely axe all of wordpress default styles.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Finding_Your_CSS_Styles

Comment: Doesn't the style.css need to be there in order to include site information, for example:
/*
Theme Name: 
Theme URI: http://wordpress.org/themes/leadmen
Description: Leadmen Request Form Wordpress Theme
Version: 1
Author: 
Author URI: 
*/

Comment: That stuff is not explicitly required but you could just delete everything underneath the theme information if you wanted to retain it

Comment: The style.css should absolutely not be deleted. As Barret mentioned, it has theme info. If you want to not use it, delete everything beneath the info.

Comment: I just tried deleting everything underneath the theme info, and migrated all that information to a second stylesheet "style2.css". I've linked it up properly and everything but when I upload and refresh, nothing looks different :( There must be a default stylesheet it's inheriting from something, urgggh

Comment: If this is on a webserver it may be cached in your browser. Try a hard reload (CTRL + R in Chrome/Windows).

Comment: Hard reload also doesn't help unfortunately

Comment: When you view an element with developer tools, does it say style2.css or style.css for the css filename it is using?