# How to get rid off default css styles in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have installed html5 blank template and I have created sub theme too by creating `style.css` and `functions.php`. But how should I get rid off default css styles that come from parent theme?

Comment: This might answer your question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22334532/wordpress-removing-default-styles

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it happens, that you make changes to your theme i.e, changes in its style.css file, and when you see your front end, things won't happens. Nothing has been changed to your theme. Usually this occurs because Wordpress loads such files from the browser cache, so clear your cache and then see your front end. Hope it helps.

Comment: yes I had put all the required information, on admin panel in `editor` under `appearance` it displays my child theme style.css file but when I try to visit the site, here it is still overriding parent's style sheet

Comment: Have you put the required above code in your functions.php file? basically the above functions.php code inherit the overall style from your parent theme, but you can override these styles by adding your own css code in style.css file of your sub theme.

Comment: Actually I am new to wordpress thats why dont know what code should be written in `functions.php` to exclude default styles

Comment: Ok go to theme section in your admin pannel of wordpress and make sure that the name of your sub theme match the name of  Theme Name: Your theme name in your header information.

Comment: yes I have activated my sub theme having the same name appearing in themes as for my parent theme

Comment: Your sub theme name should be different from your parent theme name. Like if your parent theme name is Bron then your sub theme name should be Bron Child.

Comment: yes I have append`-child` in the end of my sub themes folder

Comment: Make sure your sub theme folder name don't have any spaces. And the first line of your header information in style.css file which includes the name of your sub theme , this sub theme name must exactly match the name of your sub theme under theme section of wordpress admin panel.

Comment: when I have remove all style sheets including `style.css`, `normalize.css` from parent's directory and also remove `wp_enqueue_style($parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' ); ` from `functions.php` then my custom style sheet is working. Is there a way to remove default css using a hook inside `functions.php` rather then manually removing

Comment: yes I have some css code in child's style sheet but not working when parent's style sheets are there