# Wordpress CSS issues

Tags: html, css, wordpress, themes

I'm having some really weird issues with converting a static HTML page to a wordpress custom theme. I have a style css sheet and a foundation css sheet as I am using that frameowrk.

The CSS works perfectly on the static html page but when it goes to wordpress there are issues with the font including the colour and size. Is there a specfic way you should be importing the CSS or a conflict I should be aware of?

The CSS of both are added to the page because I can see them in style editor when I 'inspect element'. I enque the scripts as shown below;

```
// Adds the css to the theme 
function add_theme_scripts()
{       
    wp_enqueue_style('styles', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    wp_enqueue_style('foundation', get_template_directory_uri() . "/css/foundation.css" );
}    
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_theme_scripts');
```

I didn't know if it was to do with any form of config error or just faulty files so I recreated the theme from scratch and the problem persisted.
If someone could perhaps point me in the right direction it would be very appreciated. 
Thank you.

-Edit-

I've checked inspect element and removed all the addtional CSS that has been added by wordpress and the problem persists.

Comment: From what I can tell this might be a similar issue to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22334532/wordpress-removing-default-styles

Answer (score 0):

try to view source and check any other css are included in the page. May be some plugin css is conflicting with your css. If any plugin css conflicting deactivate that plugin and then change.

Answer (score 0):

If you are en-queuing css file in parent theme.Try like this

```
function add_theme_scripts()
{
   wp_register_style( 'foundation', THEME_DIR . '/css/foundation.css', array(), '1', 'all' );
   wp_enqueue_style( 'foundation' );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_theme_scripts');
```